# How to use if condition in pandas using logical operators

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have data frame

```
Software Product      Case Number    Created date   End date    CS date 
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2774904     2/3/2017                   3/4/2019
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2774203     8/7/2017       3/9/2018    7/8/2016
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2768088     9/3/2018                   1/2/2019 
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2767500     10/10/2016      3/4/2017   3/2/2015
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2764617     11/12/2017      8/5/2018   4/5/2016
```

here I am using two conditions

```
if f9 f9['Created date'] < f9['End date']
    f9['Status'] = np.select([ m2], ['EOL'])
```

and

```
if f9['Created date'] > f9['End date']
    f9['Num of days'] = (f9['Created date'] - f9['CS date']).dt.days
    m1 = f9['Num of days'].isna()
    m2 = f9['Num of days'] > 365
    m3 = f9['Num of days'] < 365
    f9['Status'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['U','L', 'N']
```

```
Software Product  Case Number    Created date   End date    CS date   Sta
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2774904     2/3/2017                   3/4/2019   L
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2774203     8/7/2017       3/9/2017    7/8/2016   Y
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2768088     9/3/2018                   1/2/2019   NMDM9607.LE.1.0      2767500     10/10/2016     3/4/2017   3/2/2015   L
MDM9607.LE.1.0      2764617     11/12/2017      8/5/2018   4/5/2016   N
```

I used above code but I got

```
File "<ipython-input-134-3943efb08731>", line 1
                    if SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

Store the result of your comparison in a variable like:

```
data=f9["Created Date"]>f9["End Date"]
```

This will return a list of booleans.Using this you can get the relevent rows which satisfy this condition and proceed further.

```
new_rows=f9[data]
```

Or you can use the .iterrows() method for a dataframe and iterate through all the records and validate the if condition for all the records individually

```
for index,item in f9.iterrows(): 
    if item["Created Date"]>item["End Date"]:
       #Perform your operation
```

I would also recommend you to parse the above columns as dates.